# Magento2 how to fix upgrade UCT tool errors

Tags: magento2, email, upgrade, uct

> **1.** 36  WARNING Extending from class
> 'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action'    that is @deprecated on
> version '2.4.5' - See    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface

> **2.** Using class 'Magento\Framework\Registry' that is @deprecated on version '2.4.5'

> **3**Using class 'Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface' that is @deprecated on version '2.4.5' - See \Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface

> **4.** Call method 'Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface::getStockItem' that is @deprecated on version '2.4.5'

> **5.** Call method 'Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder::create' that is @deprecated on version '2.4.5'

How to fix the Magento upgrade issues in 2.4.5?

Comment: Did you fix these issues? If yes let me know the steps.